# Annotate specific bars with values from Dataframe on Pandas bar plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, charts

I have a bar chart like this:

[image]

and this is the code that I use to generate it:

```py
def performance_plot_builder(data: str, ax: pyplot.Axes):
    df = pandas.read_csv(data, header=0, sep=';')
    df[['library', 'function']] = df.name.str.split('_', expand=True, n=1)
    df = df.pivot('function', 'library', 'elapsed')

    normalized = df.div(df.max(axis=1), axis=0)
    normalized.plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', color=[c.value for c in Color])

    ax.set_ylabel('execution time (normalized)')

    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))
```

The data is first normalized relative to the maximum value between the two series for each item and then plotted. I've been able to annotate the value on each bar, however I would like several modifications:

1. I only want the values displayed on the maximum of each of the two values. For example, for `array_access`, only the `stl` bar's value will be shown since it is greater than `etl`.
2. The biggest thing I need is for the non-normalized values to be displayed instead of the normalized values as it is now (so the `df` dataframe instead of the `normalized` dataframe.
3. I would also like the labels to be rotated 90 degrees so that the labels display on the bars themselves.

This is an example dataframe I have:

```
library               etl           stl
function
copy         6.922975e-06  6.319098e-06
copy_if      1.369602e-04  1.423410e-04
count        6.135367e-05  1.179409e-04
count_if     1.332942e-04  1.908408e-04
equal        1.099963e-05  1.102448e-05
fill         5.337406e-05  9.352984e-05
fill_n       6.412923e-05  9.354095e-05
find         4.354274e-08  7.804437e-08
find_if      4.792641e-08  9.206846e-08
iter_swap    4.898631e-08  4.911048e-08
rotate       2.816952e-04  5.219732e-06
swap         2.832723e-04  2.882649e-04
swap_ranges  3.492764e-04  3.576686e-04
transform    9.739075e-05  1.080187e-04
```

I'm really not sure how to go about this since as far as I can tell, the data is retrieved from the `Axes` object, however this contains the normalized values.

**Edit**

I was able to somewhat accomplish all the modifications with this code:

```py
interleaved = [val for pair in zip(df['etl'], df['stl']) for val in pair]
for v, p in zip(interleaved, ax.patches):
    if p.get_height() == 1:
        ax.text(x=p.get_x() + 0.01, y=0.825, s=f'{v:.1E}', rotation=90, color='white')
```

However, this is somewhat hard coded and only works if the bar chart values are normalized, which they are most likely to be, but not necessarily, so I would like a solution that is generic and is independent from the normalized values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out:

```py
size = len(ax.patches) // 2
for v_etl, v_stl, p_etl, p_stl in zip(df['etl'], df['stl'], ax.patches[:size], ax.patches[size:]):
    p, v = (p_etl, v_etl) if v_etl > v_stl else (p_stl, v_stl)
    ax.text(x=p.get_x() + 0.18 * p.get_width(), y=p.get_height() - 0.175, s=f'{v:.1E}', rotation=90, color='white')
```